# How to use Material UI ThemeManager for setting custom AppBar height and color?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, browserify, material-ui

I'm using the [Callemall](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) react material-ui dependency within a meteor app. I am wondering how I can change the color and height of the AppBar I'm using. Is this possible by using inline styles to [override the theme variables](http://material-ui.com/#/customization/themes)? If so, how?

```js
injectTapEventPlugin();
var {AppBar} = MUI;
var {ThemeManager, LightRawTheme} = Styles;

Header = React.createClass({
    childContextTypes: {
        muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
    },

    getChildContext() {
        return {
            muiTheme: ThemeManager.getMuiTheme(LightRawTheme);
    }
        ;
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <AppCanvas>
                <AppBar iconElementLeft={
                    <div className="header-left-area">
                        <FloatingActionButton
                            title="Register"
                            iconClassName="muidocs-icon-action-grade"
                            secondary={true}
                            mini={true}/>
                    </div>
                }/>
            </AppCanvas>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to stay away from the `inline style` prop. See [this](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/styles).

> All Material-UI components have their styles defined inline. You can
>   read the discussion thread regarding this decision as well as this
>   presentation discussing CSS in JS.
>
> However, we have experienced important limitations with this approach.
>
> - Poor performance as recomputing all the styles at each render
> - Hustle debugging
> - Server-side media queries
> - Server-side pseudo element
> - Longer time to interaction with server-side rendering (E.g. :hover)

---

We have Material UI v1.0 now.

## Material UI v1.0

You have many options to do this - look at the [implementation code](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/AppBar/AppBar.js) to understand how it works.

#### If this is your theme

```
const YourTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: createPalette({
    background: {
      appBar: '#000'
    }
  }),
  overrides: {
    MuiAppBar: {
      root: {
        background: '#fff'
      }
    }
  }

});
```

#### You have many options, here are 2:

<kbd>1</kbd> Use the default color you just coded

```
<AppBar color={'default'}>
...
</AppBar>
```

AppBar will be white `#fff`.

<kbd>2</kbd> Or Inherit the color from `palette.background.appBar`

```
<AppBar color={'inherit'}>
...
</AppBar>
```

AppBar will be black `#000`.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to go about this. One is using the inline style prop as you mentioned. This way does not work completely:

`<AppBar style={{backgroundColor='red', minHeight=50}} titleStyle={{lineHeight=50}}/>`

Reason for this is that inside the `AppBar` component, the appbar height from the theme is used in some calculations [here](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/app-bar.jsx#L119) that won't be easy to override using inline styles.

The other method which should completely work is as follows. Inside your `Header` component, choose a lifecycle method that gets executed before `render()`. Since you're only passing the modified theme down, I'll just use `getChildContext()` to demonstrate:

```
getChildContext() {
  var myTheme = ThemeManager.getMuiTheme(LightRawTheme);

  //override the properties you want to
  //import Colors from 'material-ui/lib/styles/colors'
  myTheme.appBar.color = Colors.<choose-a-color>;
  myTheme.appBar.height = 50;

  //once done overriding, pass the theme using context
  return {
    muiTheme: myTheme
  };
}
```

All of this is also mentioned in the docs for theming. See [theme-manager.js](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/theme-manager.js) for a list of exposed properties that you can override.

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the height use: `variant="dense"`

```
    <AppBar
      position="fixed"
      className={classNames(classes.appBar, {
        [classes.appBarShift]: this.props.home.openSidebar
      })}
    >
      <Toolbar disableGutters={!this.props.home.openSidebar} variant="dense">
        <IconButton
          color="inherit"
          aria-label="Open drawer"
          onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
        >
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          Tittle
        </Typography>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
```

and to change the color, I think the best way is to set on the theme

```
    const theme = createMuiTheme({
      palette: {
        primary: amber,
        secondary: {
          main: '#f44336'
        }
      }
    });

    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>{this.props.children}</MuiThemeProvider>
        );
      }
    }
```